# Spring Boot/Tomcat, "Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean"

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I know there are others questions on this, and I have checked them, but none solves my issue.

**Very simple POM**, ready:ing my app for use with an embedded web server, simply so I can start it up...

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Very easy** Boot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World from Tomcat";
    }

}
```

Tried:

- Extend the SpringBootServletInitializer class.
- Update spring-boot-starter-parent to the latest (2.1.3).
- Setting spring.profiles.active=default in application.properties.
- Manually inject TomcatWebServerFactory (ugh...) in @Configuration
  class.
- Run mvn dependency:purge-local-repository and removed /repository dir
  from my .m2 dir, fetching all again with mvn clean install -U.

ETC... I do not see why it is not working, I though Spring Boot was supposed to be easy.

> Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing
>   ServletWebServerFactory bean.

Comment: Can you please add the complete StackTrace? Which IDE do you use?

Comment: My newbie-ness reached infinity as I did not pass in my Spring Boot-annotated class to the run method, instead sending in SpringApplication.class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First argument for `SpringApplication.run()` is expected to be the primary configuration class of your application. In your case it is `SpringBootApp.class` and not `SpringApplication.class`. Following would be the correct configuration for your Spring Boot application.

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Wow, cannot believe I made that one. Works perfectly now, much thanks.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.